# How to use lazy parameter in Gurobi

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I want to add the lazy parameter and change it in my problem written in python. When I read the manual at http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/ampl-gurobi/parameters.html for the lazy parameters it says:

---

lazy:
whether to honor suffix .lazy on linear constraints in problems with binary or integer variables:

0 = no (ignore .lazy)

1 = yes (default)
Lazy constraints are indicated with .lazy values of 1, 2, or 3 and are ignored until a solution feasible to the remaining constraints is found. What happens next depends on the values of .lazy:

1 ==> the constraint may still be ignored if another lazy constraint cuts off the current solution;

2 ==> the constraint will henceforth be enforced if it is violated by the current solution;

3 ==> the constraint will henceforth be enforced.:

---

My aim is to relieve the solver. Among many parameters lazy seemed to be a good one worth trying. I could not find an example or use case for that. Does it apply to variables or constraints or to a specific type of constraint. Also what does ".lazy" correspond to?

Comment: What makes you think it will help if you don't think what it's doing? Start [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/lazy.html) and [here](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.de/2012/08/user-cuts-versus-lazy-constraints.html).

Comment: Thank you for the links. Rather I am more interested how to include it in the code. Because from the definition I understand it is a parameter added to the constraints. Am I wrong?

Comment: There is some stuff about that in AMPL's mailing-list. This also is AMPL-specific (Gurobi is just interpreting this & do stuff accordingly). I also think that your question is very broad in terms of what exactly you want to do and what you are currently doing (example: as someone not much familiar with AMPL: are you using gurobipy, which i don't think or just using python to load in AMPL-models into gurobi? of course this decides on what and how some things are possible).

Comment: Are you confusing Python with AMPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sascha and Erwin have noted, the documentation you're reading is specific to AMPL.

AMPL is a platform that can be used to define optimisation problems, independent of the solver that's used to solve them. It then translates those specs into a model appropriate to the solver chosen by the user. One of the solvers it supports is Gurobi, so there is some documentation specific to the combination of AMPL and Gurobi.

If you're programming in Python, you're probably not using AMPL, so you might want to look at http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/lazy.html instead.

In brief: "lazy constraints" are a trick that can be used when the full model definition would require a very large number of constraints, but most of them are unlikely to change the solution. In this case you can sometimes improve solution speed with the following approach:

- Set up the problem without the "lazy" constraints
- Solve this problem
- Check whether the solution violates any of the lazy constraints
- If it does, add ONLY the constraints that were actually violated, and re-solve.
- Repeat until you have a solution that satisfies all the lazy constraints.

Per documentation, Gurobi only supports the lazy option for linear constraints, but in principle the method could be used for other kinds of constraints.